# Process %1 to registry in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I need to add this value `%~dp0scss-formatter.bat %1` (`%~dp0` is folder path) and that part `%1` should saved to this value too (not as file name, but string). My whole `.bat` file looks like this:

```
@echo off
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\scss_auto_file\shell\SCSS Format\command" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%~dp0scss-formatter.bat %1" /f
```

It works well, except that `%1`. In default value I need that `%1`, so, is here any way how to do it? I mean, in registry that key will have default value, for example: `D:\Applications\scss-formatter.bat %1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it. Instead of `%1` use `%%1`.